# LINQ to SQL .Count takes way to much process time and decreases performances

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

LINQ to SQL .Count takes way to much process time and decreases performances.

I am doing a recursive loop and for one child (lets call it parent) I have to check the number of children under it to make a decision if it should be included or not.

The Count is too slow 8 ms :( for 120 parent records.

Any ideas to make it quicker.

Comment: Can you post the SQL that is generated?

Comment: How many items are being counted?  Can you supply an example of you approach?

Comment: Please post some code - if the real code is too big or otherwise cannot be posted, make a small example with the same behaviour, that will help getting better answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could select a projection from your database getting the parent and the count of child element it has. This avoids round tripping to the database.

```
var query = from x in DataContext.Parents 
            select new {Parent = x, Count = x.Childs.Count() };
```

Now loop over the results and to whatever you want to next.

If you just want to filter (=where clause) based on the child element count, do it like this:

```
var query = from x in DataContext.Parents 
            where c.Childs.Count() > 10
            select x;
```

Linq to SQL will try to translate your calls to `IEnumerable.Count()` to a `SELECT COUNT(*)`, which should be pretty performant.

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like you are looping over a result set, doing *another* Linq-to-sql query for each result. In that case it is bound to be slow since you will be doing a lot of extra database roundtrips.

You will have to rewrite your question to get the children count together right away in the first query.

Comment: Na not doing another Linq-to-sql

There is the parent and the children entity sets

Comment: Just calling `Count()` on the children reference is indeed another linq-to-sql query (although a very simple one) that will result in another sql query roundtrip to the database.

Comment: @Johannes Rudolph has an excellent code example in his answer, using `select new` to get both the parent entity and the child count.